# How do I use jQuery Mobile's $(document).bind('pageinit') properly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, page-init

I'm have the following in the head of one of my pages:

```
<script>
$(document).bind('pageinit' , function(){ alert("welcome"); });
//$(document).ready(function() {alert("welcome"); });
</script>
```

That which is commented out works fine (when uncommented), but the top one does not.  I'm running into a lot of issues because of the jQuery Mobile pageinit feature.  I have to click refresh after navigating to every page or the scrollbar I added plus other features won't load.  The scroll bar plugIn I referenced like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="cubiq-iscroll-bad88fb/src/iscroll.js"></script>
```

Yet like I said every time I navigate from one page to another it won't load seamlessly.  I need to click refresh.  I assume this is because of the Ajax and I think the problem is solved by properly using    `$(document).bind('pageinit')` but I'm lost on how to do it.  Any advice is really appreciated.  Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the event to the `div` representing the page, for example:

```
$( '#thePage' ).live( 'pageinit',function(event){
    alert( 'This page was just enhanced by jQuery Mobile!' );
});
```

Where `#thePage` is the `id` of your page `div`.

See the [JQuery Mobile docs](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/api/events.html) for this example and more information.